# Can't compile IntelliJ Android app with references to Maven libraries

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ.  I have an Android project from which I'm trying to use bitcoinj.  In IntelliJ, I go to File | Project Structure... | New Project Library | From Maven..., search for "bitcoinj" (which is found as "com.google:bitcoinj:0.11.1") and then add it, which also adds it to my Android module's dependencies tab.

However, when I use "import com.google.bitcoin.core" in my Android app's source, I get the following compiler error:

Error:(5, 1) java: package com.google.bitcoinj does not exist

I get this same behavior no matter what library I add.  Being new to IntelliJ, I'm obviously missing something simple, but haven't been able to find an through Google searches.

Comment: Is your project a Maven project, too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependency to the pom file of your project. That is only way to add dependencies to a Maven project. IntelliJ only looks at Maven poms in order to build your project.

What you described just opens the other project in the IDE right next to your project with absolutely no relation to it.

See https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/wiki/UsingMaven

As it is not on mvnrepo, do the following: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html